# CMD Set only reading first letter in text file

Tags: variables, cmd, set, output, command-prompt

Using the following command    `Set /p out=<out.txt`    I do not get the text in the
 file, what is returned is just a symbol and the first letter in the file.

I've tried using    `Set out=more out.txt`    but that ends up just placing the 
command "more out.txt" into the script instead of what's in the text file.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU9A1.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that the `out.txt` is saved using [`UTF-16` encoding with BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Unlike [`type` command](https://ss64.com/nt/type.html), the [`<` redirection operator](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) does not understand this. The following `cmd` command should do the trick:

```
set out=&for /f "delims=" %G in ('type out.txt') do @if not defined out set out=%G
```

To use the `FOR` command in a batch script (`.bat` or `.cmd` extension), specify `%%G` instead
of `%G` as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
set "out="
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('type out.txt') do if not defined out set out=%%G
```